# How to create a new sheet and copy the respective values into the new sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with around 3000 values, I want to be able to look through the values and copy the duplicates into a different sheet. 
The different sheet is basically a new sheet with the value.

For example:

[image]

In this case, I would want the macro to go through the list and copy all the values which are same i.e. all the "ALNASRAQ" ones and create a new sheet with the name "ALNASRAQ" and paste the values in there.

I need to do that for all the values. So, basically a new sheet for each unique value and everything with that value has the data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample script for you which can help you to read data from one sheet and use it in other sheet.

https://adarshpatel.wordpress.com/2013/04/29/gtu-result-summary-generator/